# How to link a placeholder image in react-app

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am new to react. I have to link a placeholder in my react-universl static page. What is the syntax to do it? Thanks in advance. I tried 
1. image src="http://placehold.it/150x150" 
2. image src={"http://placehold.it/150x150"} 
3. image src={require('http://placehold.it/150x150')}

Is there a way to do it? Or do i have to make changes in webpack? Thanks in advance.

Comment: #1 is correct except that the tag name is `img` not `image`. (#2 also works btw)

Answer (score 1):

The proper answer is `<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />`, just like in plain HTML.

If you are a beginner, make sure to learn HTML and JavaScript ***before*** you start learning React.

Comment: @mukhilsaravanan You're sure you used `img`, not `image`?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without manually adding the `src` would be running client JS to loop through all the `<img>`s and add the `src` attribute